# Сортировка списка в Python с параметром reverse

Tags: python, сортировка

При сортировке такого списка

```
A = [22, 44, 11, 12, 99, 88]
```

с помощью метода *sorted* с объявленными параметрами *key* и *reverse*

```
B = sorted(A, key=lambda x: len(str(x)), reverse=True)
C = sorted(A, key=lambda x: len(str(x)), reverse=False)
```

на выходе получается два одинаковых списка B и С, а именно:

```
[22, 44, 11, 12, 99, 88]
```

Почему так происходит?

Comment: что такое `len(str(x))` и чему оно равно ?

Comment: Просто длина элемента.

Comment: чему она равна?

Comment: В данном примере - везде 2.

Comment: так и что вы ожидаете получить ?

Comment: Отсортированный по длине элементов список.

Comment: вы его получили `[22, 44, 11, 12, 99, 88]`

Comment: Да. Но вопрос в том, почему при разных параметрах для reverse в отсортированных списках одинаковый порядок элементов.

Comment: попробуйте отсортировать `A = [22, 4444, 1, 333, 99, 88]`

Comment: вы же только что написали `В данном примере - везде 2.`

Comment: Это всё понятно.
Не понятно, почему на выходе получаются 2 одинаковых списка, а не 
`B = [22, 44, 11, 12, 99, 88]` и `C = [88, 99, 12, 11, 44, 22]`

Comment: потому что у вас все элементы одинаковой длины? то есть, сортировать-то нечего по вашим параметрам. Вам предложили попробовать сортировку, добавив в список трехзначный элемент. Сами все увидите.

Comment: И т. е. из-за этого и не происходит реверс для В и С?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Параметр `reverse` явно задаёт порядок сортировки, а не разворачивает список в конце.
В этом и есть принципиальное отличие. Т.к. в вашем случае для сортировщика все элементы равны, вы и получаете два равных списка для прямой и обратной сортировки.

Хотите получить два зеркальных - используйте `sorted(A, key=lambda x: len(str(x)))` и `reversed(sorted(A, key=lambda x: len(str(x))))`, тогда результаты всегда будут зеркальными